# Wordpress in same directory with default page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I think I'm needing help with .htaccess here.

I have a page that was named index.php.  I still need that to be the default page but with a new name AND I need a wordpress install in the same root.  So here's what I've done:

1. Renamed index.php to somethingelse.php
2. Created an .HTACCESS with this line in it: DirectoryIndex somethingelse.php

Now if I go to www.site.com it brings up the www.site.com/somethingelse.php page (as it should).

Next I installed Wordpress into the root.  That went well too.

The problem is I cannot access wordpress via www.site.com/index.php when I do that it just kicks me back over to somethingelse.php page

I'm thinking there is something I need to add to .htaccess so that if:

1) Someone types www.site.com it goes to www.site.com/somethingelse.php
2) Someone types www.site.com/index.php it goes to the wordpress install

Just for clarity, the reason for this is that in about a week, somethingelse.php will go away and the wordpress install will be the live site.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide your current htaccess (the one with rewrite rules created by WordPress). I have a bit different approach in mind: if `www.site.com/` is accessed, then silently display `somethingelse.php` via specific RewriteRule rather than using `DirectoryIndex` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a separate page that only I can get to to set and destroy a cookie.  then in the header.php of the WP file I check that cookie and determine where to go.